# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ProductID'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Friends i have properly bind the  dropdown with dataset but it is giving this error:
my codes are:

To Bind-Data Set

```
 DataSet ds = new ViewAction().GetAllProductInfoData();
            ddlprdctname.DataSource = ds;
            ddlprdctname.DataTextField = "ProductName";
            ddlprdctname.DataValueField ="ProductID";
            ddlprdctname.DataBind();
```

and GetAllProductInfoData() function is

```
 public DataSet GetAllProductInfoData()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = DataConnection.GetConnection().CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select ProductID ProductName,SubCategory2ID,CompanyID,Price,Quantity,Description from ProductInfo";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            cmd.Dispose();
            DataConnection.CloseConnection();
            return ds;
        }
```

What is the error please hellp me to solve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a comma in your query after `ProductID`. As written, it is understanding `ProductName` to be the returned column name *alias* for `ProductID`, and not a separate column as you most likely intended.

Your query as written is equivalent to:

```
Select ProductID AS ProductName, SubCategory2ID, ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a comma in your query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select ProductID, ProductName, ...
```

Without the comma, the query selects the `ProductID` column using the alias `ProductName`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with gridview and got this error you can simply remove unneccessary data from of template.

```
 <asp:CheckBox runat="server"  />
```

as shown above remove this error.