# Showing 5 row from dataset to asp.net repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have dataset in session object with all user record 
 somewhere I have to show all ( 200 row) record some where only 5 in asp.net repeater control

I am trying to show 5 record/row but now working still showing 200 record

```
DataSet tempDS = (DataSet)Application["ActivityDS"];

//I tried both but now working
tempDS.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(5);
OR 
tempDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Take(5);

repSearchResult.DataSource = tempDS;
repSearchResult.DataBind();
```

what I have to do for showing 5 row from dataset to asp.net repeater control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
var datasource=tempDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Take(5);
repSearchResult.DataSource = datasource;
repSearchResult.DataBind();
```

You can also take a look to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx

> **Return Value Type:** `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>`
>
> An
>   `IEnumerable<T>` that contains the specified number of elements from the
>   start of the input sequence.

So, with this method you are not modifying the original sequence, a new `IEnumerable` is created and returned.

Comment: before binding repeater control I have added one column  PicPath ...that is giving an error : DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'PicPath'.

Comment: @KrantiSingh thet's another thing, it's not related to this question.
You can take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813964/databinding-system-data-datarowview-does-not-contain-a-property-with-the-name